# Find $T(n)$ from $T(n^3)$

Tags: algorithms

Consider
$$\begin{align} T(n^3)&=T((n-1)^3)+n\\
T(1)&=1
\end{align}$$

According to the substitution method, $T(n^3)=O(n^2)$ (please if I wrong, correct me). Now, what is the answer of $T(n)$? I think $T(n)=O(1)$ but the answer of my teacher is $T(n)=O(n^\frac{2}{3})$.

Comment: Please explain how you find $O(1)$. [Which is just not possible as $T(n^3)\ge n$.]

Comment: In fact the question is incomplete. From the recurrence, you can only evaluate $T$ at perfect cubes, and you know nothing about the intermediate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function $S(n) = T(n^3)$. Then $S(n) = T(n^3) = T((n-1)^3 + n = S(n-1) + n$, and $S(1) = T(1^3) = T(1) = 1$. The answer is obviously the sum of n from 1 to n, or $n(n+1) / 2$.

So $S(n) = T(n^3) = n(n+1) / 2$, and $T(n) = n^{1/3} (n+1)^{1/3} - 1$ whenever n is a cube of some integer.

Just try T(1000) = T(729) + 10 = T(512) + 9 + 10 = ... = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55. It's often useful not to just do some formula manipulation but use real numbers (I think there's a quote by Euler about that, after he worked all night proving a completely nonsensical result once).

Comment: I don't get your final answer. Isn't it $\dfrac{\sqrt[3]n(\sqrt[3]n+1)}2$ for $n$ a perfect cube ?